# Trace of each matrix in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list of multiple matrices, I want to compute the trace of each matrix.

```py
np.asarray([[[1,2,3],
             [4,5,6],
             [7,8,9]],
           [[10,11,12],
            [13,14,15],
            [16,17,18]]])
```

The result should be:

```py
np.asarray([15, 42])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `axis1=1` and `axis2=2` arguments in `np.trace`.

`np.trace(x, axis1=1, axis2=2)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) along the second axis:

```
a = np.asarray([[[1,2,3],
                 [4,5,6],
                 [7,8,9]],
               [[10,11,12],
                [13,14,15],
                [16,17,18]]])

a[:, range(a.shape[1]), range(a.shape[2])].sum(1)
# array([15, 42])
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there some function which is more readable? I was thinking about apply_along_axis or apply_over_axis, ...

Comment: For more readibility apparently you can also use the `axis` arguments in `np.trace`, as proposed by @shivam

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.trace` function with arguments `axis1=1` and `axis2=2`

```py
mat = np.asarray([[[1,2,3],
             [4,5,6],
             [7,8,9]],
           [[10,11,12],
            [13,14,15],
            [16,17,18]]])

np.trace(mat, axis1=1, axis2=2)
```

output :

```py
array([15, 42])
```